# GraphQL ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree when building my docker container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, graphql, dockerfile

Here are my files.

Here is I think the core of the problem.

```
Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer graphql@"^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0" from graphql-middleware@4.0.2
```

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  apollo:
    container_name: apollo
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
        -  NODE_ENV=development
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'

    ports:
      - 4000:4000

    restart: always
```

## Dockerfile

```
# Use the official image as a parent image.
FROM node:current-slim

# Set the working directory.
WORKDIR /app

# Setting environment path.
ENV PATH=/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# Copy the file from your host to your current location.
COPY package.json .

# Run the command inside your image filesystem.
RUN npm init --yes
RUN npm install --save cors apollo-server-express express graphql reflect-metadata type-graphql apollo-datasource-rest soap jsonwebtoken --yes
RUN npm install nodemon -g --yes

# Add metadata to the image to describe which port the container is listening on at runtime.
EXPOSE 4000

# Copy the rest of your app's source code from your host to your image filesystem.
COPY . .
CMD [ "nodemon", "index.js" ]
```

## Dependency Error

```
$ docker-compose up --build
Building apollo
Step 1/10 : FROM node:current-slim
 ---> f3f62dfcc735
Step 2/10 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 33088e65c748
Step 3/10 : ENV PATH=/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
 ---> Using cache
 ---> c7f742267b26
Step 4/10 : COPY package.json .
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 76285ea4a8ca
Step 5/10 : RUN npm init --yes
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 29a3d715136b
Step 6/10 : RUN npm install --save cors apollo-server-express express graphql reflect-metadata type-graphql apollo-datasource-rest soap jsonwebtoken --yes
 ---> Running in 1e4472bcd901
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: apollo-express-server@1.0.0
npm ERR! Found: graphql@15.4.0
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql
npm ERR!   graphql@"^15.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer graphql@"^0.12.0 || ^0.13.0 || ^14.0.0" from graphql-middleware@4.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/graphql-middleware
npm ERR!   graphql-middleware@"^4.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! See /root/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2020-11-05T16_19_42_605Z-debug.log
ERROR: Service 'apollo' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c npm install --save cors apollo-server-express express graphql reflect-metadata type-graphql apollo-datasource-rest soap jsonwebtoken --yes' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The problem here is certainly with NPM and the packages you are trying to install rather than anything to do with Docker.

Unfortunately, I am not able to reproduce the exact error that you are facing. That could be because:

- something changed in the time between now and whenever this problem occurred;
- there are some essential details that you are not showing us.

Either way, there's a general way in which such issues are solved, which should help. But first an explanation.

### Dependencies, peer dependencies and conflicts

NPM's package (dependency) management mechanism allows packages (dependencies) to have:

- (direct) **dependencies** - installed automatically with the package;
- **peer dependencies** - have to be manually installed by the consumer of the package.

However, NPM does **not** allow multiple versions of the same package to coexist.

Also, as you may know, packages use standard semantic versioning, which means that a major version change indicates a breaking change.

Due to these two reasons, clashes occur if one package requires dependency A to be v1, while another wants the same dependency A to be v2.

### NPM v7

NPM v7 was recently released and this is the version that current (as of November 2020) `node:current` images use.

Probably the biggest changes brought about by NPM7 relate to peer dependencies - NPM should now be able to install them automatically, *if possible*. [Read more here](https://github.com/npm/rfcs/blob/latest/implemented/0025-install-peer-deps.md).

As described in the document, in cases where it's not possible to solve the conflicts, NPM should now throw *errors* rather than warnings, which is what you are seeing.

I, on the other hand, only managed to get warnings and no errors using your setup and NPM v7.0.8, and **I don't know why**. The problems reported were essentially the same, however, so the resolution ought to be very similar.

### How to solve conflicts

The only solution that I'm aware of is manual conflict resolution - the developer needs to adjust their dependencies to play along.

In your specific case the problem seems to be with the `graphql` package. The latest `graphql` package is v15, which is also a peer dependency of the latest `type-graphql` package (v1).

However, `apollo-server-express` has a few dependencies, which apparently only support `graphql` up to and including v14.

While you wait for `apollo-server-express` to fully support v15, you may opt for `graphql` v14 altogether by downgrading the only package that requires v15. So if you change your `npm install` to this:

```
npm install --save cors apollo-server-express express graphql@14 reflect-metadata type-graphql@0 apollo-datasource-rest soap jsonwebtoken
```

it ought to work... Notice that we are explicitly installing `graphql@14` and `type-graphql@0` (yes, version zero).

### Alternative solution

Going to give you some bad advice too. In some cases a missing peer dependency may not be a problem, particularly if you never use the related functionality. In your case, it may be even less of a problem because you **do** have the dependency, just not the required version. It's entirely possible that a wrong version would do just fine. If you feel lucky (or if you're sure of you're doing) and you really wish to proceed with `graphql` v15, you could either:

- suppress any NPM output to silence the errors;
- downgrade to NPM v6, which works quite differently (although it will still warn you of peer dependency problems).

**Proceed with caution**!

Answer (score 19):

There is not need to downgrade to npm 6.
Indeed npm 7 can still be used with option --legacy-peer-deps.

```
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
```

Comment: This solution still work with npm 8.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar error, in my case just need to manually install all dependencies

```
npm install --save express
npm install --save express-graphql
npm install --save graphql
npm install --save mongoose
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a similar issue with ```express-grahql``` after upgrading from Gatsby 2.x to 3.3.1. express-graphql was not on the main package.json so installing it added it to the package.json and fixed the warning. With similar warnings I guess looking for the package in the package.json and not seeing it is the first thing to fix.

Answer (score 2):

```
npm install package_name --legacy-peer-deps
```

Or

```
npm install package_name --force
```

Will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while trying to build a reactJS application in which i had used CoreUI and other JS libraries. Some of this dependacies i noted they use legacy dependacies in them and seemed like in their `package.json` file they have explicitly specified a version to be used. After trying all this solutions above, docker (*docker build .*) still could not build my image.

i changed my base image from `node:16-alpine3.11` to `node:12-alpine3.11` and everything worked perfectly.
Using this base image i was able to avoid using

`npm install --save --legacy-peer-deps`  which failed to work on my case

My recommendations to anyone who might experience this issues is to just try various node docker images.