# npm install unable to resolve dependency tree

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

So I bought the premium dashboard theme from Creative Tim's site and now when I am trying to work on it I am unable to install the packages. When I run `npm install` I get the following error:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: argon-dashboard-pro-react@1.2.0
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-bootstrap-table-next@4.0.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-bootstrap-table-next
npm ERR!   react-bootstrap-table-next@"4.0.3" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-02-08T12_06_48_302Z-debug.log
```

How to fix this error. I've tried --legacy-peer-deps and --force as well.  Nothing seems to work.

Comment: remove node_models folder and packge-lock.json and run npm i

Comment: this is answered here [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718633/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718633/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-reactjs)

Comment: What `node-sass` and node version do you have?

Answer (score 7):

I faced this issue and either of the two solutions worked for me. They are:

1. `npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

   In case you are curious what it does?
   The packages will install with the --legacy flag. The command ignores all
   peer dependencies when installing, in the style of npm version 4 through
   version 6.
2. This error comes from version 7.x of npm. Hence, another solution is to
   downgrade to npm 6.x.

Reference : [Refer this for more info](https://blog.npmjs.org/post/626173315965468672/npm-v7-series-beta-release-and-semver-major)

Answer (score 4):

I encountered a similar error and adding --legacy-peer-deps resolved it for me.
`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`.

Read more about '--legacy-peer-deps' [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66020820/npm-when-to-use-force-and-legacy-peer-deps).

Comment: is this hack fix or is there a way to solve the issues?

Answer (score 2):

Try this commands

`npm cache clean --force`

`npm install --legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 1):

Using a force/ legacy --legacy-peer-deps is to accept a incorrect peer dependency, its better to figure out what are the peer dependency for the package u are trying to install , and see its peer dependency version and the update your projects dependency to match the peer dependency of the package