# How do I fix this issue in react native project - "npm ERR! Invalid tag name ">=^16.8.1"" this issue?

Tags: react-native, node-modules, npm-install

I am getting this error when install the node modules(npm install). Why this issue happening in react native project? Is this related to node version ?

**Error :**

> npm ERR! code EINVALIDTAGNAME npm ERR! Invalid tag name ">=^16.8.1":
> Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes. npm
> ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> /Users/abcdef/.npm/_logs/2021-08-02T05_31_11_609Z-debug.log

**Error Log (debug.log)**

109 verbose stack Error: Invalid tag name ">=^16.8.1": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
109 verbose stack     at invalidTagName (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:89:15)
109 verbose stack     at fromRegistry (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:343:13)
109 verbose stack     at Function.resolve (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-package-arg/npa.js:80:12)
109 verbose stack     at Arborist.[nodeFromEdge] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:949:37)
109 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[loadPeerSet] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:1170:23)
109 verbose stack     at async Arborist.[buildDepStep] (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:886:11)
109 verbose stack     at async Arborist.buildIdealTree (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/build-ideal-tree.js:218:7)
109 verbose stack     at async Promise.all (index 1)
109 verbose stack     at async Arborist.reify (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/@npmcli/arborist/lib/arborist/reify.js:134:5)
109 verbose stack     at async Install.install (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/install.js:150:5)
110 verbose cwd /Users/abcde/Project/XXX/Workspace/xyz-app
111 verbose Darwin 19.6.0
112 verbose argv "/usr/local/Cellar/node/16.4.2/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i"
113 verbose node v16.4.2
114 verbose npm  v7.20.2
115 error code EINVALIDTAGNAME
116 error Invalid tag name ">=^16.8.1": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
117 verbose exit 1

Comment: Q: Is your command line exactly `npm install` (and *NOTHING* else)?  Q: Can you show us the relevant part of the log ("2021-08-02T05_31_11_609Z-debug.log").  In particular, exactly which file is NPM encountering the error on?

Comment: @paulsm4 - Added error log from debug.log file

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65093533/421195 and try adding this: `--legacy-peer-deps`

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this issue. We can fix this issue in two ways,

1. Downgrade the npm version(In my case, I have downgraded it to 6.14.14 after that it's working fine.)

> npm install -g npm@6.14.14

2. In the terminal, navigate to your project root directory and run this

> npm install --legacy-peer-deps