# Need help bypassing type errors in floating-ui module. (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

package.json

```
{
  "name": "lifestyle-monitor-app-ui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2", 
    "@babel/plugin-transform-block-scoping": "7.20.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/core": "^11.0.0",
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@floating-ui/dom": "^1.5.1",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.12.4",
    "@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.61",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.7.4",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/history": "^4.7.11",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.38",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "getmdl-select": "^2.0.1",
    "hashids": "^2.2.11",
    "material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
    "mdl-selectfield": "^1.0.4",
    "mui-datatables": "^4.3.0",
    "patch-package": "^8.0.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-calendar": "^4.0.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-key-index": "^0.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-select": "^5.7.0",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-uuid": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "3.8",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

[image: Error in floating-ui library]

Steps taken to resolve the error.

1. Deleted the node_modules folder and reinstalled using npm.
2. Updated VS Studio.
3. Changed @floating-ui/core to dom based on the suggestion here:- https://github.com/floating-ui/floating-ui/pull/2513

Need advice on how to proceed further. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The following fix suggested under this thread helped me fix my issue. Thank you stackOverFlow :-)

[Getting npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve when I give npm install in my node project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72917969/getting-npm-err-eresolve-could-not-resolve-when-i-give-npm-install-in-my-node-p)