Unable to resolve dependency tree Error in react js while installing npm package
enter code hereWhen I try to install react-sortable-tree npm package getting error like "unable to resolve dependency tree" and solution for this is given in that error message "Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution."
What's the right way to go about fixing this upstream dependency conflict? without using --force or --legacy-peer-deps how can I fix it?
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: react-sortable-tree@0.1.0
npm ERR! Found: react@18.2.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.3.0" from react-sortable-tree@2.8.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react-sortable-tree
npm ERR!   react-sortable-tree@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2024-04-25T05_31_59_043Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/user/.npm/_logs/2024-04-25T05_31_59_043Z-debug-0.log

In my package.json I have "react": "^18.2.0".

Similar question with answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64718633/unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-reactjs

The error message indicates a version incompatibility between react-sortable-tree and your installed react version. react-sortable-tree has a peer dependency on react@^16.3.0, meaning it's explicitly designed to work with React versions 16.3.0 and above but not necessarily compatible with newer major versions like 18.
Solutions:
Here are two approaches you can take to resolve the conflict:
1. Downgrade react (Recommended):
If react-sortable-tree is essential for your project and you don't require the latest React features, consider downgrading react to a compatible version within the ^16.3.0 range. You can do this by modifying your package.json:
JSON
{
"dependencies": {
"react": "^16.14.0" // Choose a compatible version within the range
}
}
After updating package.json, run npm install again to install the compatible react version and react-sortable-tree.
Explore Alternatives (if downgrading isn't feasible):
2. If downgrading react isn't an option, you might need to consider alternative sortable tree libraries that are compatible with React 18. Here are some options to explore:
react-dnd-html5-backend:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-dnd-sortable
react-beautiful-dnd:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-beautiful-dnd
Important Considerations:
Downgrading react may mean sacrificing some of the latest features and bug fixes. However, if react-sortable-tree is critical and works well with your project, it might be a worthwhile trade-off.
Carefully evaluate alternative libraries based on their features, documentation, and community support before making a decision.

Thanks for sharing.I tried react-beautiful-dnd and react-dnd-html5-backend ,still issue persist.
