# ERESOLVE while Heroku pushing

Tags: node.js, heroku, graphql-upload

While doing `git push heroku main`, ERESOLVE occurred:

[image]

I deleted `node_modules/` and `package-lock.json` and reinstalled it
but it didn't work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64701308/graphql-eresolve-unable-to-resolve-dependency-tree-when-building-my-docker-conta.

Comment: Thank you. But it did not solve my problem.

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.